# RegEx Filter for common words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to remove common words (conjunctions, adverbs, pronouns,etc) from a block of text. I am using a regex but for some reason, some of the common words that are in my filter are not getting filtered out.

Some examples of words not being filtered:  "havent", "why", "should"

Any ideas why?

```
 splitResult = s.split()
        p = re.compile(
            """^(&amp;|also|a|about|again|all|after|are(nt)?|arent|as|an(y)?|at|
                bcuz|before|be(low)?|between|bring|but|by|and|can(not)?|close(d)?|could(nt)?|
                cuz|do(nt)?|down|decide(d)?|decision|on(to)?|or|of|our|over|out|have(nt)?|he(re)?|
                her|his|other(s)?|even|got(ten)?|for|from|get(s)?|got(ten)?|has(nt)?|havent|he(s)?|
                him|his|if|in|to|in(to)?|is(nt)?||make|me|once|play(ed)?|role|say(s)?|seen|she(s)?|
                should(nt)?|stop(ped)?|time|my|no(t)?|must(nt)?|now|you(re)?|your|want|want(ed)?|
                watch(ed)?|way|we(re)?|will|with||i|a|is(nt)?|just|would(nt)?|before|that|the(re)?|
                their|them|they|this|turn|when|at|how|it(s)?|which|who|after|then|if|how|because|know(s)?|
                yet|[A-Za-z]{1,2}|http(s)?://.*|www\..*)$""",re.I)

        for word in splitResult:
            m = p.findall(word)
            if not m:
                word = "".join(c for c in word if c not in ("?", ".", "!", '"', ",","'","(",")"))
                wordsList.insert(ctr,word)
```

Comment: I think this is a more suitable job for Natural Language Processing, see, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953619/technique-to-remove-common-wordsand-their-plural-versions-from-a-string.

Comment: I put this in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wR0dJ2/1), and you can see the error in the *Explanation* section (though it does not highlight it). Basically you have `is(nt)?||make`, which should be `is(nt)?||make` and `with||i`, which should be `with|i`. Both had 2 `||` instead of 1. This does not solve the problem, but I would suggest you update your RegEx

Comment: I could not find any issue, I just turned capturing groups to non-capturing for a cleaner output: see [demo](http://ideone.com/mnC7nr). Note that you can contract this pattern more to make it more efficient by grouping keywords that have common endings.

Answer (score 0):

## Your pattern does not have `why` as one of its alternations.

It seems that your pattern has become so large that you are unable to manage it.

## Your pattern does not match when there is surrounding whitespace or apostrophes.

There's no reason that `havent` and `should` will fail to filter, otherwise. Without more code, nobody knows.

(The following is a bug in regex101.com, but you should nonetheless fix your regex accordingly.)

According to regex101.com there are two of the following errors:

> `|` Alternator at this position effectively truncates the group, rendering any other tokens beyond this point useless

## This means there are `||`s in your code, essentially.

Note: If you want to match nothingness (the equivalent of an empty string), there should not be alterations afterwards, as this regex engine matches the earliest alternation it can.

Here they are:

- `||make`
- `|with||i`

(Found with the regex: `\|\|`)

Comment: That's a nice catch. The error message, hiwever, could be improved :) A double `||` makes the regex match 'nothing', at that point - it does not really truncate. (Well it does, but all within the rules.)

Comment: @RadLexus I didn't pick that wording. Go tell `regex101.com` that.

Comment: I realize that || I just thought of explaining the problem.

Comment: The `||` has no effect since the pattern is anchored at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I looked into it, and found a [bug report](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/219). I will go back and see if I can better answer the question.