# NLTK how to remove common vocabulary, instead of just stop words?

Tags: nltk, stop-words

NLTK can be used to remove stopwords. [Technique to remove common words(and their plural versions) from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953619/technique-to-remove-common-wordsand-their-plural-versions-from-a-string)

However, is there a library contain the "common words" such as "near", "science", and thus select the "uncommon words" such as "attractor" etc. ?